# How to click on particular button if multiple buttons are having same classes in protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automation, protractor

Html code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" ng-click="move(1)" tabindex="-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

In angular protractor, is there any way to click on particular button if multiple buttons are having same classes. Please help me out on this.

Comment: The subject and the actual question are entirely different. Can you clearly state what you want to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can click on the button by :-

By Id :

```
 element(by.id('id')).click().then(function() {
 });
```

By xpath :

```
element(by.xpath('//div[@id="ui-datepicker-div"]//a[@title="Next"]')).click(); // whatever your xpath is
```

Comment: He said the button has same class and no id.

Answer (score 0):

you can distinguish the button by the button text. Like yiu can grab the element (button) by button text and perform your desired action

```html
<button>Save</button> 
element(by.buttonText('Save'));
```